# GIMP How to use python console (or make plugin) to navigate between images

Tags: image-processing, autoit, gimp, script-fu, python-fu

***Note: This applies to windows only, due to the inherent problems from using standard, free automation tools for (EDIT: GDK) applications on Windows.  If there is a better way to work with automating GDK on Windows than AutoIt, please let me know)***

I am trying to automate some tasks in GIMP using AutoIT mostly, which is mostly simple enough, however, moving from open image to open image is problematic.  There are two ways I have done this (using AutoIt) so far: Automatically click on the arrows (in single window mode) to scroll from image to image, and 2) using right and left arrow KEYS to do same.

There are problems with both approaches. For the first approach I can not do anything else with my computer until the AutoIt script is done processing because it is occupying my mouse. And we are talking about 100 or so images each time.

For the second approach it requires, I do not know the proper word, but 'thumbnail bar' at the top, that the thumbnail bar be 'active' or else using arrow keys does not work. you CAN make it active by clicking on an image inside of it, once or twice depending on state, but then I have to do all sorts of gymnastics to know which ACTUAL image I am supposed to be on in order to proceed.

That brings me to conclude the best solution is to have some programmatic way, in a Python or Scheme plugin (or a simple command or two, that I can have AutoIt simply paste into the console) to allow me to move between images in a very reliable, non-obtrusive, simple way.

Thank you in advance.
Dev

Comment: What are you actually trying to do to the images - there may be better tools.

Comment: Hi, well, I am doing some batch processing on each image, BUT unlike the ones floating around for GIMP, I wan to do it on OPEN images. Not files loaded from disk.

Comment: So you were basically looking for gimp.image_list() and want to iterate over that?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you can't. By design, the script-fu and python-fu API deal with images processing and cannot interfere with the UI. You can just open windows (a.k.a. "displays") on images and delete them (and only those your script created).

But you can write Python/Scheme scripts to do the tasks directly instead of trying to do them by emulating a human...

Comment: OK, I was hoping to avoid having to learn how to write a plugin myself as I don't  believe(right now at least) that I will ever do so again.  But if this is the only way...